# How to autostart monerod in Windows 10?

Tags: monerod, windows

I would like some assistance starting monerod.exe when starting Windows from boot. Can someone please walk me through this?

Answer (score 2):

## Preparation

Make sure you have the latest binaries from the [official website](https://getmonero.org/downloads/). Download and extract these. Make a shortcut of `monerod.exe`. If you would like to run the daemon with certain parameters, create a .bat file and then create a shortcut of the .bat file instead. You can create a shortcut of a file by right clicking a file and then clicking `Create a shortcut`.

## Adding the Shortcut to the Startup Folder

Windows has several startup folders. You can either put it in a folder that runs when a certain user logs in, or in a folder that runs for all users.

#### Specific User

Go to `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`, replacing `Username` with your actual username. Copy the shortcut here.

Alternatively, you can open `Run` and type `shell:startup` to get to this folder.

#### All Users

Go to `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp`. Copy the shortcut here.

Alternatively, you can open `Run` and type `shell:common startup` to get to this folder.